# cargar input en vue.js

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vue.js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]La situación es que tengo un método get, el cual me trae los datos de una medición, estos datos serian para crear un actualizar, pero debo cargar los imput con los datos que me responda la api que esta desarrollada en asp.net core, el problema es que no logro hacer que se me llenen los input con los datos que me responde el server.

para ejemplo, tengo los datos y input `NISE:""`, y `Medi:[]`,

lo que hago por el momento es que lo que me responde el server me lo meta en un array medi,

```
Actualizar(idMedicion) {
    let me = this;
    axios
      .get("api/MedicionPrincipals/" + me.idMedicion )
      .then(function(response) {

        me.medi = response.data;
        me.nise = me.medi.NISE;

      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
```

este es el input que deseo llenar por el momento

```
<v-flex xs12 sm6 md4>
  <v-text-field
    type="number"
    label="# NISE"
    placeholder="# NISE"
    v-model="nise"
    prepend-inner-icon="label_important"
  ></v-text-field>
</v-flex>
```

en la imagen se puede ver por que vienen los datos.

Comment: Esto no funciona? tenes algun error en la consola?

Comment: no amigo, en la consola si me trae todos los datos, pero no logro hacer que a la hora de uo darle el botton de buscar, me  llene los campos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

me.medi lo igualaste a response.data

A su vez,
me.nise quieres igualarlo a me.mide.NISE
Pero en el response obtienes medidor

Utiliza lo siguiente

```
me.medi = response.data.medidor;
me.nise = me.medi.nise
```

Con minúsculas

Comment: hola señor muchas gracias , eso era solo que ahora estoy teniendo un problema , la situaico es que me dice que NISE me dice que no esta definido, me lo tira como advertencia en la pagina al darle inspeccionar    me.nise = response.data.medidor.nise lo hice asi, ya que tengo que traer varias tablas,